# I want to know the meaning of "一批教学设备"

Tags: translation

Found the sentence "学校购买了一批教学设备。" inside the vocab book.

Google translation has showed me "The school purchased a batch of teaching equipment." as the translated sentence.

I can't understand "a batch of teaching equipment" here.

In the first place, is this translation even correct?

Comment: Do you have problem with "一批" ? Or "教学设备"?

Comment: Both. I need to know some examples of 一批教学设备 .

Comment: A bunch (batch) of laptops, projectors and old fashion stuff like blackboards, chalks etc.

Comment: Ahh, now i understood the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 批 is "a measure word" for batches, lots, of goods/materials/equipment with a quantity usually more than a few. So the translation is correct.